# php Return only variables from array into the webpage

Tags: php, python, arrays, html

I am currently screwing around with php and python. I've made a simple python script which is literally just - `print "Hello World"`

My php script (which is inside my index.php main page) is as follows:

```
<?php 
$output = null;
exec('C:\\Python27\\python.exe py\\test.py', $output, $return);
print_r($output);
?>
```

My problem is that it returns this:

Array ( [0] => Hello World )

Does anyone know how to only return `Hello World` into my webpage?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: passthru() possibly http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php

Comment: Yeesh do i feel like a dumbass... Thank you both.

Comment: Passthru seems to supress error messages when in DOS mode.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (is_array($output)){
     foreach($output as $v) echo $v . "<br>";}
else echo $output
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to replace print_r($output) with echo $output[0].

But as the exec-Statement returns an array with every line, it only works with a single-line return-value from the python-script. If you really want the whole output, you have to loop through the array.

Comment: This doesn't make the exec function to not return an array. So this isn't a solution, it's more to take care of the symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

When specifying an output variable, it would fill it with an array of every line of output.

Instead, save the actual result of the exec function to a variable, and echo that.